# What is the difference between Tagbuilder and @helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I don't understand what the difference is between a tagbuilder and @helper

For example:

```
@helper TestHelper(string name , string id , int value)
{
    if(value>3)
    {
        <p name="@name" id="@id">@value</p>
    }
}
```

The helper can create a tag, so why  or when we use the tagbuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@helper` is used to define re-usable helper methods in view. For ex in your case you have defined the `TestHelper` to generate a `<p>` tag based on some condition so wherever you require `<p>` tag, you can call `TestHelper` method. While `TagBuilder` is used to create a new tag with a specified tag name. For example the below extension method used TagBuilder to generate an img input.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MvcApplication1.Helpers
{
    public static class ImageHelper
    {
        public static string Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string url, string alternateText)
        {
            return Image(helper, id, url, alternateText, null);
        }

        public static string Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string url, string alternateText, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            // Create tag builder
            var builder = new TagBuilder("img");

            // Create valid id
            builder.GenerateId(id);

            // Add attributes
            builder.MergeAttribute("src", url);
            builder.MergeAttribute("alt", alternateText);
            builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

            // Render tag
            return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
        }

    }
}
```

Now to render you can define it as

```
@Html.Image("img1", <<Src of image>>, <<Name Of Image>>)
```

TagBuilder provides the capability of adding classes, merging attributes too. You can read about TagBulider [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder(v=vs.111).aspx)

Comment: it seem the helper can do the same job if i use helper to create the img tag

Comment: @helper creates common method; not the tags.